# imshow function in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using imshow function to display images in OpenCV. It works fine, there is just a little thing though: the title I write for the image is not correctly displayed.

For example, when I write "Original" or "inverted" they are displayed with some extra and unintelligible data in the beginning. However, when I write "thresholded Image" a long line of unintelligible words is displayed instead of the title...

It does not effect anything else but it seems queer to me. Do you have any idea why that happens?

Here is my code:

```
IplImage* image=cvLoadImage("Black&White.jpg");
Mat image1;
image1=Mat(image,false);
imshow("Image",image1);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Comment: [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: We could not help you without more info. Show us your code

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you are using the C and C++ libraries interchangeably - IpIImage belongs to C and Mat belongs to C++, this could be the source of your problem. Instead, try just using the C++ interface and your code will be as follows :

```
Mat image = imread("Black&White.jpg"); 
imshow("Image",image);
waitKey(0);
```

That should fix your problem, if not, try using the C interface

```
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("Black&White.jpg");
cvNamedWindow( "Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cvShowImage("Image", image);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Comment: well I've tried this many a time but the function imread() is not working properly with my compiler:( It doesn't pick the image!!! while cvLoadImage() picks images from the same locations without any issue,that's why I am reading image in IplImage format and then converting it into Mat form...@Matt McGrath

Comment: Hi Aayman, Okay, I'll edit my answer to add the C code since the imread won't work for you

Comment: Thank you:) the cvShowImage() works fine but it doesn't display Mat images...@Matt McGrath

Comment: It's not advised to cross over between the C and C++ libraries, you will probably have to avoid using Mat images and just use IplImage and  it's cvLoadImage and cvShowImage

Comment: are you sure the path you are providing is correct ? have you taken care of case sensitiveness ? Also, just for peace sake, can you try removing that `&` from the same of the file ?

Comment: yep,I've tried to do this many a time!!! and that "&" is not an issue in cvLoadImage!!!@ Ritwik G

Answer (score 0):

Have you really checked that you used the proper link to the file?
In my case, I usually check it by doing:

```
image = imread( "C:\\\CloudStation\\\Bestanden\\\VisualStudio2010\\\Projects\\\TMerger\\\Debug\\\black_and_white.tif")
```

So in my case, I have to use a double backward slash.

Hope it helps.

greetings,
Floris.